# Jquery .text sometimes doesnt work with flask?

Tags: html, jquery, flask

I have a small jquery script that should modifiy text passing through flask.
I use ajax to do so.

```
<i class="fas fa-heart likesspot" name = "{{spot.titre}}" style="color:#e86c60" ></i> <span id = "{{spot.titre}}_l">{{spot.likes}}</span>

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.likesspot').click(function(){
         console.log($(this).attr("name"))
         var name = $(this).attr("name");

         var fct = '/addlikesspot/'+name;
         console.log(fct)
         $.ajax({  type: 'POST',  url: fct,
         success: function(data) {
                 console.log(data.matching_results);
                 console.log(name);
                 $("#"+name+"_l").html("<b>"+data.matching_results[1].toString()+"</b>" );
                  },
        });
     });
});
```

note that each time I click the console log returns
console.log(data.matching_results);
console.log(name);
with the good values

note also that the span is in a carroussel and it seems that the first carousel page always works whereas other page works randomly

Comment: its is .html in the example but same results with .text